# app crash when keyboard appear. Survey_kit with Flutter

Tags: flutter, survey

I am writing a survey using Flutter and a library called survey_kit. When Keyboard appear to wirte QuestionStep (in TextAnswerFormat), the app crash and I get this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Controller's length property (19) does not match the number of children (37) present in TabBarView's children property.
```

**Code**

```
import 'package:survey_kit/survey_kit.dart' as survey;

survey.QuestionStep(
          title: question.title.toString(),
          answerFormat: const survey.TextAnswerFormat(
            maxLines: 5,
            validationRegEx: "^(?!s*\$).+",
          ),
        )
```

Can someone post an example how to access it ? Any help greatly appreciated! pk

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to share some code?

This problem occurs when the number of tab bar items inside your tab bar children property is not equal to the length given to this tab bar.

The main reason could be that you are trying to build the TabBar, before knowing how many tabs will be displayed.

I can be more accurate if you share some code.

Comment: I use Survey kit package : https://pub.dev/packages/survey_kit/install